# A certain decategorification of a monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory

The usual decategorification $K(C)$ of a monoidal category $C$ is by taking the isomorphic classes of $C$ as objects. The resulting decategorification $K(C)$ is a monoid.

There is another decategorification that takes the morphisms as objects instead. The result is also a monoid. Is there a name for and literature on this?

EDIT: Let me clarify after Boris' comment. Start with a pointed monoidal category $C$. Then the set of arrows $Arr(C)$ is a monoid with the tensor product and the identity arrow.

Comment: Sorry, do you consider the morphisms as objects and the commutative triangles as morphisms (and obtain a new category)? Either do you consider the morphisms as elements with the operation of composition (and obtain a semigroup rather than monoid)?

Comment: This is the 'decategorification' of the monoidal category of diagrams with shape $\circ\rightarrow\bullet$

Comment: I'm not sure if Fernando has answered what you want, but I felt like I should add that $Arr(C)$ has another monoidal structure given by the pushout product...$f_i:X_i\rightarrow Y_i$ has $f_0\square f_1: X_0\otimes Y_1 \coprod_{X_0\otimes X_1} Y_0\otimes X_1 \rightarrow Y_0\otimes Y_1$. I wonder what you get when you take isomorphism classes with respect to this rather than the standard $\otimes$ in $Arr(C)$

Comment: Another decategorification is $C \mapsto \mathrm{End}(1_C)$.

Comment: Thank you all for explanations. I missed the word "monoidal" :-(

Comment: Yes, Fernando answered my original question. The decategorification in my edit is the functor category $[\cdot\to\cdot,C]$. Thank you Boris for allowing me to clarify my intended decategorification. As pointed other, there are really several (different) decategorifications.

Comment: @Martin yay! I love that map!